# How can I tell if my grill pan is preseasoned?

Tags: equipment

I bought  [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019NA00M) grill pan, and someone told me it may be preseasoned. It doesn't say anything in the description. How can I be sure?

Comment: It's labelled as "nonstick".  "Nonstick" and "preseasoned" are different things.

Comment: Nonstick is not optimal for a grill pan btw - the temperatures you want in a grill pan are murder on any nonstick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the information on [starfrit.com](https://www.starfrit.com/en/10-34-25cm-grill-pan-with-foldable-handle) , there is no mention of the pan being pre-seasoned. But there is also no mention of needing to do so.

From the maintenance tab on the linked page:

> Before you cook
>
> - Remove all labels and packaging materials.
> - Before using your new cookware, wash thoroughly in hot soapy water using a soft cloth or sponge. Dry completely.
>
> General cooking tips
>
> - Prior to each use, it is recommended to add a teaspoon of cooking oil for better cooking results.
>
>   - Never heat an empty utensil. Be sure there is oil, butter, liquid or food before placing the cookware on the range
>       or burner.
>   - It is not recommended to use high heat. Cooking on excessive heat can cause permanent damage to the surface and
>       utensil.
>   - Never cut anything in the cookware or use utensils with sharp edges as to avoid damaging the surface.
>   - Add salt to water only after is has come to a boil. Salt grain deposit on the cookware bottom will attack the metal as
>       the heat melts it down.

There is also other information about cleaning and oven use.

All said, I don't follow a set rule about seasoning non-stick cookware even though I've often seen it recommended. But when I have heated oil in a non-stick pan it does seem to do better afterwards, especially with older pans. And I *always* hand wash non-stick cookware.

To sum up, I don't see how you could cause any harm by pre-seasoning the pan and occasionally reseasoning, even if it doesn't need it. But this is based on my experience and I haven't used this brand.

The only other thing I can suggest is to contact the company and see what they say. Since they don't mention pre-seasoning, I suspect they will say it isn't necessary. If you do contact them, we'd be interested in what you find out.

And welcome to Seasoned Advice!

**EDIT:**

I was assuming that the OP knew about seasoning a non-stick pan, as the question is about how to tell if a non-stick pan is pre-seasoned when new.

To be very clear, seasoning a non-stick pan is **NOT** the same thing as seasoning a cast iron or other bare metal pan. Should you (or anyone) decide to season a non-stick pan, please make sure to follow a recommended procedure.

Comment: " I don't see how you could cause any harm by pre-seasoning the pan and occasionally reseasoning" - you will cause harm First, even the best seasoning done on a bare-metal pan is not as good at being non-stick as actual nonstick coating. Second, seasoning does not deposit well on a nonstick pan, so you end up with patchy seasoning, which is very unpleasant to cook with. Third, the process of seasoning, no matter if successful or not, is hot enough to damage the nonstick properties of the existing coating. So, you give up all advantages of a nonstick pan without gaining much in return.

Comment: @rumtscho Please research how to season a non-stick pan. It is not the same procedure as seasoning a cast iron pan, nor does it use the high temp involved in seasoning cast iron. Also, you are not building up seasoning as you would with a bare pan. It is quite different and shouldn't harm the pan. And some non-stick cookware is sold as being pre-seasoned.

Comment: OK, I looked into it and removed the downvote. It still seems to be controversial, but maybe worth a try if the OP feels like it. I will keep my own Teflon pans unseasoned though, I would be too wary of accidentally developing an actual polymerization, which is a huge PITA on them.

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks. I edited the answer to be clear that it is a very different thing.

Comment: Was asking because of allergies to some of the seasonings. I emailed them to be sure, but good answer.